# How can I get attributes of elements selected with two classes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This seems like it should be simple, but I am having difficulty.

I need to select elements in my `DOM` that have both the `checkbox` and `selected` class applied, so I am using the **JavaScript** code:

```
var queries = $(".checkbox.selected");
for (var i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
    console.log(queries[i]);
}
```

which prints out:

```
[<div class=​"checkbox selected">​Option 1​</div>​, 
 <div class=​"checkbox selected">​Option 2​</div>​]
```

The issue is, when I use `queries[i].text()` (inside the loop), I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: queries[i].text is not a function
```

So it looks as if my `queries` is not a list of DOM objects. **How can this be?** I've tried this multiple ways I can't access the `Option 1` or `Option 2` text at all. *Has anyone run into this error? Am I accessing the elements correctly?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have jQuery objects of those elements when you access by index, only the plain elements. You would have to do this:

```
var queries = $(".checkbox.selected");
for (var i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
    console.log($(queries[i]).text());
}
```

But that's really ugly, use jQuerys own [each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
$(".checkbox.selected").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Ah! This makes sense. I learned something new about jQuery! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> So it looks as if my queries is not a list of DOM objects

Try utilizing `.textContent` to return text within `queries[i]` `DOM` element

```js
var queries = $(".checkbox.selected");
for (var i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
  console.log(queries[i].textContent);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="checkbox selected">Option 1</div>
<div class="checkbox selected">Option 2</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason you're getting an error with `queries[i].text()` is because you're invoking a jQuery method on a DOM element; `queries` is a jQuery collection but, `queries[i]` is a DOM element. Given a DOM element, to access jQuery methods you want to jQuery-wrap the DOM element:

```
$( queries[i] ).text()
```

However, I would use jQuery all the way -- jQuery [.each() method](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
var queries = $(".checkbox.selected");
queries.each( function(i,query) {
    console.log( $(query).text() );
});
```

Or:

```js
    $(".checkbox.selected").each( function(i,query) {
        console.log( $(query).text() ); //output: Option 1\nOption 2
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox selected">Option 1</div> 
<div class="checkbox selected">Option 2</div>
```